# HTML Marquee with jQuery Ajax Auto Refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using HTML `marquee` to show information.

Now to get the content, I use jQuery Ajax Auto Refresh with `setInterval` every second.

HTML

```
<marquee>
    <ul class="runningTextList" id="runningTextList"></ul>
</marquee>
```

jQuery

```
$('#runningTextList').empty();
for(var i=0; i<jsonStr.runningText.length; i++)
{
    var runningText = jsonStr.runningText[i];

    var newOption = $('<li><i class="glyphicon2 glyphicon-info-sign"></i> '+runningText+'</li>');
    $('#runningTextList').append(newOption);
}
```

I don't know why when I put data to table with long length, the data will not show.

PHP

```
$qRunningText = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_running_texts WHERE active = 'Y'");
while($dRunningText = mysqli_fetch_array($qRunningText))
{
    $runningText[] = $dRunningText['running_text'];
}

$data = array(
    "runningText"     => $runningText
);

echo json_encode($data);
```

And the result of jSon

```
{"runningText":["Ahlan wa sahlan","Luruskan shaf-shaf kalian, karena sesungguhnya merapatkan a","Test 1"]}
```

As you can see on this:

```
Luruskan shaf-shaf kalian, karena sesungguhnya merapatkan a //This will not show, I don't know why but if I remove " a" I can see the data.
```

If I remove `a` to be:

```
Luruskan shaf-shaf kalian, karena sesungguhnya merapatkan
```

Data can be show.

How is it? Is there any something wrong code?

*If I remove `<marquee>` tag I can see all data.

Comment: *Please* do not use `<marquee>`. There are much better, more powerful solutions using JS libraries.

Comment: If using JS libraries, is it possible to set auto refresh content there?

Comment: I thought I was viewing this question via archive.org when I saw someone asking about HTML marquee...